# Change order of conditions when plotting normalised counts for single gene

Tags: r, rna-seq

I have a df of 17 variables (my samples) with the condition location which I would like to plot based on a single gene "photosystem II protein D1 1"

```
View(metadata)

sample location
   <chr>  <chr>   
 1 X1344  West    
 2 X1345  West    
 3 X1365  West    
 4 X1366  West    
 5 X1367  West    
 6 X1419  West    
 7 X1420  West    
 8 X1421  West    
 9 X1473  Mid     
10 X1475  Mid     
11 X1528  Mid     
12 X1584  East    
13 X1585  East    
14 X1586  East    
15 X1678  East    
16 X1679  East    
17 X1680  East
```

```
View(countdata)

func X1344 X1345 X1365 X1366 X1367 X1419 X1420 X1421 X1473 X1475 X1528 X1584 X1585 X1586 X1678 X1679 X1680

photosystem II protein D1 1 11208   6807    3483    4091    12198   7229    7404    5606    6059    7456    4007    2514    5709    2424    2346    4447    5567
```

- countdata contains thousands of genes but I am only showing the headers and gene of interest

ddsMat has been created like this:

```
ddsMat <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = countdata,
                                  colData = metadata,
                                  design = ~ location)
```

When plotting:

```
library(DeSeq2)
plotCounts(ddsMat, "photosystem II protein D1 1", intgroup=c("location"))
```

By default, the function plots the "conditions" alphabetically eg: East-Mid-West. But I would like to order them so I can see them on the graph West-Mid-East.

Check [plotCountsIMAGEhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5O4F.png)

Is there a way of doing this?
Thanks,

Comment: try to relevel your location vector using a factor.

Comment: @Jimbou could you be more specific? How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that you can manually change the order like this:

```
ddsMat$location <- factor(ddsMat$location, levels=c("West", "Mid", "East"))
```